# How to encourage students to answers questions from other students posted in Q&A online places dedicated to the classroom (e.g. Piazza)

Tags: teaching, motivation, answering-questions

How can an instructor or teaching assistant encourage students to answers questions from other students posted in private Q&A online platforms dedicated to the classroom (e.g. Piazza), put aside from adding some percentage of the final grade based on such activities?

Comment: Why do you want a Q&A?

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Students sometimes ask questions, in the hope of having an answer.

Comment: Why online?  Why should students answer instead of faculty?

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Online for convenience. Answers from students reduce the load of the teaching staff while being educative for them.

Comment: I disagree with any efforts to reduce the involvement of faculty in education.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist They can make use of this gain of time by working on other parts of the course (e.g. improving lecture notes).

Comment: The answer to this question is "by explaining to them how this will help them achieve the learning objectives of this course," but the details of this explanation will vary depending on the course. If it *doesn't* help them achieve the learning objectives, then I'm with them on this one.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Increasing student involvement does not imply decreasing faculty involvement.

Answer (score 2):

I used Piazza in my undergraduate business and society course last year. Students were required to participate, but I found that if I myself commented on some of their posts and then brought up some of their arguments in class that this encouraged more active posts. In particular I made a point of highlighting debates between students during subsequent class periods.